# initWithCoder not working as expected in Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am using Sprite Kit engine. I used to write code in `initWithSize` but since the update, `initWithSize` is not called automatically, instead `viewDidLoad` is called. I got to know that instead of `initWithSize`, `initWithCoder` had to be used, so i changed the code from:

```
-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
        SKSpriteNode *paddle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"paddle"];
        paddle.position = CGPointMake(150, 100);
        paddle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        [self addChild:paddle];
    }

    return self;
}
```

to:

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
        SKSpriteNode *paddle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"paddle"];
        paddle.position = CGPointMake(150, 100);
        paddle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        [self addChild:paddle];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now, the color of the scene turns blue, but i am not able to add sprites to the scene. Neither do I get any error while building.

Are there some changes that I should make in `initWithCoder`? (If yes, please specify and elaborate)

Can `initWithCoder` be used with EXACTLY the same code as we did in `initWithSize`?

PS: Heres the full code I have in GameScene.m and I do not have any other scene.

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

/* Setup your scene here */

}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {

        SKSpriteNode *paddle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"paddle"];

        paddle.position = CGPointMake(150, 100);

        paddle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        [self addChild:paddle];



    }

    return self;

}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

/* Called before each frame is rendered */

}

@end
```

And I just copied and pasted the code from initWithSize to initWithCoder. It doesn't seem to create the paddle object.

Please help!

Comment: post the code that creates the sprite, otherwise we can't tell you why it's not getting called

Comment: I am using the following code to create the sprite from an image imported into the project:

        SKSpriteNode *paddle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"paddle"];


        paddle.position = CGPointMake(150, 100);


        paddle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


        [self addChild:paddle];

Comment: skspritenode has no initWithSize initializer, you are probably mistaking it with SKScene

Comment: So how do  i fix it?

Comment: sorry, i was on the wrong track here, you do seem to have a skscene here so it's important to post the code where you create and present that scene. Perhaps you are doing [SKScene node] or alloc/init rather than initwithsize?

Comment: I have added my full code in the description. Please check and help! :)

Comment: That's not the code that creates the scene. If you expect initWithCoder to run you will have to use unarchiveFromFile or something on the GameScene class.

Comment: I don't understand, can you be more specific? Give me an example by making changes to my code, perhaps? I am a noob sorry.

Comment: if you want GameScene initWithCoder to run, then [GameScene unarchiveWithFile:..] or similar needs to be called to create the game scene from an SKS file

Answer (score 0):

It may be a method signature mismatch?

Instead of instancetype it is defined as: `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`

I was just looking up if I could have the type safety of instance type in my keyed coding implementations and found your question.

Others say it works.  It would be worth a test.
[Why does initWithCoder not return instancetype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143209/why-does-initwithcoder-not-return-instancetype)