# Why does initWithCoder not return instancetype?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscoding, instancetype

It seems that most `init` methods in Objective-C now tend to return `instancetype` instead of `id`. See [`[UIView initWithFrame:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:), [`[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:), [`[NSArray init]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/init) and siblings, etc. But [`initWithCoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder:) uses `id`. Why is this? Has it just not been updated yet? Or is there a reason it has to be `id`?

Comment: It uses `instancetype` as of iOS 9/OX 10.11

Comment: `instancetype` [is implicitly understood for `init...` anyways](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not updated yet. You can still code it with instance type.

```
     - (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        //...
    }
    return self;
}
```